# What do I call the "non-start pages" of a website?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, translation

I have a table with website banner advertising rates. There are two sub-columns: one is titled "Start page" (the price of the banner is higher if it is placed on the start page) and "Section pages" (Russian term which means that the banner is placed on a "non-start" page, in some of the website's sections accessed from the start page).

What does one call these pages in English? Is there a special term, or maybe one simply calls them "ordinary pages"?

> [image]

Comment: Arrrgh! The main page is called the *landing* page, but I don't know about others. I would just call them *content* pages (unless they have other purposes, such as help pages).

Comment: @Mick - I think that a website can have several landing pages, so it's probably better to call it [home page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_page) or "start page", because the Russian phrase clearly means  "main page". Thanks for "content pages"!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thank you! I always make this mistake, because in Russian we use the word "how" there. )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Subpages" would work. Or '"all other pages"

You can also talk about

- "Level 1 page" i.e. main page
- "Level 2 pages" linked from start page, or header menu
- "Level 3 pages" linked from level 2